# Proving absolutely convergence in the disc

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to solve the example below, but I can not.

**Use the Hardy-Littlewood theorem to prove that the Taylor series about the orign for $(1-z)^{1/2}$ is absolutely convergent in the disc.**

Please, you will be very grateful if someone would help resolve the communities in this example. Previously thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know which theorem of Hardy and Littlewood you are supposed to use here. Maybe I use something of the sort below, maybe I don't.

Write $f(z)=(1-z)^{1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n$.  Differentiating $f $ (or using the binomial formula) we notice that all coefficients $c_n$ with $n\ge 1$  are negative. (Indeed, $f'(z)=-\frac12 (1-z)^{-1/2}$, $f''(z)=-\frac34(1-z)^{-3/2}$, etc: the coefficient in front stays negative.) Therefore, we must show the convergence  of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-c_n)$. This amounts to the uniform boundedness of the partial sums of  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-c_n)$ from above.

Note that   for any $r\in (0,1)$ the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-c_n)r^n = 1-(1-r)^{1/2}$ is at most $1$.

Given $N$, pick $r\in (0,1)$ such that $r^N\ge \frac12$. Then 
$$\sum_{n=1}^N (-c_n)\le  2 \sum_{n=1}^N (-c_n r^n) \le  2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-c_n r^n) 
\le 2
$$
and we are done.